# Stub Lightning Data Service response in Lightning Test Service (Jasmine)

Tags: lightning-data-service, lightning-testing-service

Using Jasmine I can simply stub response as this before `$T.createComponent`:

```
  $A.enqueueAction = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake((action) => {
    var cb = action.getCallback("SUCCESS")
    cb.fn.apply(cb.s, [{
      getState: function() {
        return "SUCCESS";
      },
      getReturnValue: function() {
        return [{
          "Name": "Edge Communications",
          "Id": "0010q00000000000A2"
        }, {
          "Name": "Burlington Textiles Corp of America",
          "Id": "0010q00000000000A3"
        }]
      }
    }]);
  });
```

How can I do the same with Lightning Data Service?